# PIE.htc не хочет работать

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Вообщем то сначала при использовании PIE, элемент просто напросто пропадал в IE 7,8
Затем я скачал немного более старую версию и теперь элемент остается на странице но PIE не действует, элемент по прежнему квадратный, border-radius не пашет.

Бросил PIE в ту же папку что и css файл.

```
#ava {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 70px;

    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 17px;

    background-image: url(../images/ava.jpg);

    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    behavior: url("PIE.htc");

}
```

Кто ни будь подскажите как его заставить работать и какая версия нужна!!

Comment: Люди повсюду пишут что PIE у них не работает, кто то пишет что там работает а там нет, никто толком не понимает в чем проблема.

Comment: прочитайте http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/html5-and-css3/css3-pie.html, проверьте пути и заголовок

Comment: да все классно, в .htaccess прописал нужную строчку, путь срабатывает! но, скрипт отрабатывает таким образом что элемент становится просто прозрачным! это беда, это не фикс ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

путь должен быть относительно корня, а не css файла. Например если файл в папке css, то так /css/PIE.htc. По поводу исчезновения, обязательно у родителя и самого блока должен быть указан position, либо relative либо absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте внимательно [Known Issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/).

В первую очередь обратите внимание на:

- *Problems on certain element types.* Элемент обязательно должен находится в каком-либо контейнере. Т.е. так

  ```
  <html><body><input id="ava"></body></html>
  ```

работать не будет, правильно так:

```
    <html><body><div><input id="ava"></div></body></html>
```

- *Problems with hasLayout.* Т.е. обязательно нужно применять хак с `zoom:1;`.

Answer (score 0):

дописал

```
position: relative;
```

костыль сработал!
можно закрывать!